# How to implement Lock in Java/C application

Tags: java, concurrency, native

I have concurrency problem with Android application. Base of a problem is that Java code is trying to invoke C function and set value through JNI interface before C code is loaded. I have `MainActivity.java` which invokes C function and `NativeLib.java` which loads C shared library.
Is there any elegant way to solve  this concurrency problem, eg. by setting from C some Java field to `true` when loading is finished and locking MainActivity method until that value is true? Or maybe there is some other, better solution?

[image: Basic principle of engine]

This is a basic diagram of engine. In `GLThread`, in loop, method `guardedRun()` calls onDrawFrame() that sends JNI call to C to render frame and then, when `guardedRun()` receives new GL frame, it swaps frame buffer.

Problem is with method `onMessageReceived()`. Now, I want to connect Activity on startup with another device, and when it connects, I want to receive message that will be sent from Java to C. But the trouble is that C isn't loaded yet and Java is already up and connected. So, how does C says to Java: "wait until I'm loaded"?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is:

*Ensure the C code is loaded before invoking the C function*.

We can not provide much detail in our answers until you provide detail in your question.